# Renaming file names from two files content in linux

Tags: linux, renaming

I am having basic knowledge in Linux and need your help to develop concept for following requirement. I have two files FILE_NAMES.txt and FILE_NAMES_TS.txt. The content of files as below.

```
FILE_NAMES.txt
====
jan_
feb_
mar_

FILE_NAMES_TS.txt
====
jan_20170921.csv
feb_20170921.csv
mar_20170921.csv
```

All the above content are nothing but file names and are placed in db_views/data directory. For the content of `FILE_NAMES_TS.txt` are 0 bytes initially. Now have to move / rename from `jan_` to `jan_20170921.csv`, and so on. That means the file `jan_20170921.txt` is now non-zero bytes. Please help.

Comment: The question is unclear.  You begin with exactly 2 files names `FILE_NAMES.txt` and `FILE_NAMES_TS.txt` and the latter is empty?  Or do you begin with many files, including files names `jan_`, `feb_`, etc. and you want to move `jan_` to `jan_20170921.csv` and add an entry into `FILE_NAMES_TS.txt`?

Comment: No need to add entry. Just have to move jan_ to jan_20170921.csv and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readarray bash function to read files into 2 arrays and then use mv command to rename each file

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray a < names.txt
readarray b < names_ts.txt

len=${#a[@]}

echo $len

for (( i=0; i<${len}; i++ ));
do
    echo mv ${a[$i]} ${b[$i]}
done
```

Comment: Thank you Richard for sharing code. The command "readarray" will not allow in my current Linux environment. Is there by alternate command to execute the script. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the [special file-descriptor technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521498/8586227) to read from two files simultaneously and then `mv`.